# How can I generate every combination of pattern of 4 numbers and 2 A-Z characters

Tags: php, loops, combinations

I wrote a small script to talk with a database that I got from a friend so I can link a dutch zip code with a street name. But I want to do it by myself

The ZIP codes are build up like `NNNNCC` where `N` is a number 0-9 (Ignoring the first 0's 0000-0999 isn't possible) and `C` = character A-Z.

How can I generate every possible combination in `PHP`?

Comment: Take a look at recursion: https://www.elated.com/php-recursive-functions/

Comment: So you need `1000AA` through `9999ZZ`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple foreach nested loop as:

```
foreach(range(1000,9999) as $num)
    foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $c1) 
        foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $c2)
            $res[] = $num . $c1 . $c2;
```

I am not at my computer so sorry for syntax error if any (you may need to convert the `$num` to string but I guess PHP will handle it...

Comment: I was just about to write something similar. Works for me but PHP runs out of memory due to the array assignments; even outputting directly to the browser causes some serious data across the wire. I hope OP is inserting this into a DB or something.

Comment: Elegant solution, very minimal and easy to see what's going on. I prefer wrapping even my one-line blocks in brackets, but this is just so compact, so extra points for that!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus you could use a generator to take care of the memory issues if you were  doing something with the values immediatly

Comment: @Brice I don't have much experience with generators but couldn't you avoid memory issues by dealing with the values directly within the loop here instead of assigning to `$res[]`? Do generators support syntax like `echo generator()[54];` so that I can fetch the 55th combination?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You would wrap the answer in a function, and put `yeild` in place of `$res[] =`. Then you can do
`foreach(generatorFunction() as $value){`
      `doWhateverYouWantTo($value);`
`}`
and instead of having to hold an entire array in memory you just do whatever you want in real time, which I guess you don't actually need a generator for it's just an idea.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm currently working on a database with like 7m records. I want to data to store immediately in the database instead of being used in an array (because that will cause some serious issues when I'm out of memory :P )

Answer (score 1):

To build on @dWinder answer. You could build a list.

```
foreach(range(0,9999) as $num)
    foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $c1) 
        foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $c2)
//      This comes out to 6,760,000 items
//          $zips[] = sprintf("%04s%s%s<br>", $num, $c1, $c2);
```

If you just want to check format you can do pattern matching.

```
echo testZipNl('1t00AA') .' 1t00AA<br>';

echo testZipNl('11000AA') .' 11000AA<br>';

echo testZipNl('1000AA') .' 1000AA<br>';


function testZipNl($input){
    $input = trim($input);
    $regex = "/^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}$/";
    if (preg_match($regex, $input) AND strlen($input) == 6) {
     return 'True';
    }
 return 'False';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a simple pager like function to avoid the memory issue:

```
<?php

function codeRange(int $start, int $end) {
    $codes = [];
    $number = $start - 1;
    while ($number++ !== $end + 1) {
        $letter = 'AA';
        while ($letter !== 'AAA') {
            $codes[] = sprintf('%s%s', $number, $letter++);
        }
    }

    return $codes;
}

echo codeRange(1000, 1010)[0] . PHP_EOL;       // output: 1000AA
echo codeRange(1000, 1010)[1] . PHP_EOL;       // output: 1000AB
echo codeRange(1000, 1010)[2] . PHP_EOL;       // output: 1000AC
echo codeRange(1000, 1010)[7434] . PHP_EOL;    // output: 1010ZY
echo codeRange(1000, 1010)[7435] . PHP_EOL;    // output: 1010ZZ
echo codeRange(9979, 9998)[0] . PHP_EOL;       // output: 9979AA
echo codeRange(9979, 9998)[14195] . PHP_EOL;   // output: 9999ZZ
```